# How could I change opengl starting coordinates

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to figure out how does glOrtho work. I always have (0, 0) point in (w/2, h/2) means it the center of my opengl widget, however I changed this behaviour with glOrtho:

```
void Widget::initializeGL() {
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0);
}

void Widget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.2, 0.7);
    glEnd();
}

void Widget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, (GLdouble) w, (GLdouble) h, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

So I always get the same picture[image]

I want the coodinates were starting from left bottom or top left corner, but not from the center.

Comment: If you are in the earlier stage of learning OpenGL, you should stop learning old OpenGL and learn the modern OpenGL which utilizes shaders.

Comment: Thanks CroCo. Do you mean opengl 4 methods? I have videocard which support opengl 3 only.

Comment: Yes you can use shaders with OpenGL 3. Don't waste your time with old stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reset the matrix mode to model-view after setting the projection matrix. So the call to `glLoadIdentity()` in `paintGL()` will reset any projection matrix you have set up.

```
void Widget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    ...
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Keep in mind that this will draw something that is less than a pixel large. So you may want to change your geometry, too.

Btw, if you are just starting, I would recommend not to learn the deprecated OpenGL matrix stack or `glVertex2f`. It might be easier on first sight, but you will hit a wall in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out how does glOrtho work. I always have (0, 0)
>   point in (w/2, h/2) means it the center of my opengl widget, however I
>   changed this behaviour with glOrtho:
>
> ```
> glOrtho(0.0, (GLdouble) w, (GLdouble) h, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
> ```

No, you did not change anything with `glOrtho` - you are not using `glOrtho` at all. Your `glOrtho` call will just generate a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error and do *nothing else*, because it is invalid to cal it with `near == far`. As a result, you are using an identity matrix as projection, and this means that (0,0) is the center of the screen, (1,1) to top right corner, and so on.

So even if you fix your code to not overwrite the projection matrix with an identy matrix, as @Nico Schertler suggested,it won't change a thing.

I also second Mr. Schertler's recommendation: don't use this old crap. Fixed function pipeline is deprecated for almost a decade, and immediate mode (`glBegin/glEnd`) is out of fashion since *20 years*.